# Spring Boot test with yaml properties by profile

Tags: java, spring, configuration-files

So there's a lot of hits on this topic, but none of them have worked for me.

I have a very simple configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "props")
public class TagIncluder {

    private static final String PARAMETER_NAME = "tags";

    private List<String> tags;

    public TagIncluder() {
        tags = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    @Handler
    public void attachIncludedTags(Exchange exchange) {
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(PARAMETER_NAME, tags);
    }
}
```

I want this class to be able to load different property files. I am using yaml, and my file is named `application-tag_test.yml`. I have tried placing this file in `src/main/resources`, `src/test/resources` and `src/test/resources/config`, but it is never picked up.

This is the contents of the property file:

```
props:
  tags:
    - test
```

And finally, the test case:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("tag_test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TagIncluder.class)
public class TagIncluderTest extends ExchangeTestSupport {

    @Autowired
    private TagIncluder sut;

    @Test
    public void attachIncludedTags_shouldUseTagsInFileIfFileSpecified() {
        Exchange testExchange = createExchange();
        sut.attachIncludedTags(testExchange);

        Assertions.assertThat(testExchange.getIn().getHeader("tags", List.class))
            .size().isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(1);
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have tried placing an `application.properties` file in the above described locations with the following content:

```
spring.profiles.active=tag_test
```

What is required for Spring to set my yaml file as the desired configuration for my test class under test?

**UPDATE**

So after some exploration and trial and error, I have found that the following works:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("tag_test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TagIncluderTest extends ExchangeTestSupport {

    @Autowired
    private TagIncluder sut;

    @Test
    public void attachIncludedTags_shouldUseTagsInFileIfFileSpecified() {
        Exchange testExchange = createExchange();
        sut.attachIncludedTags(testExchange);

        Assertions.assertThat(testExchange.getIn().getHeader("tags", List.class))
            .size().isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(1);
    }
}
```

The difference here is that I've removed the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation and I let Spring take care of all of that.

It is a lot slower, and I would prefer specifying what is needed. I think this might break in the future, for instance if I add another configuration class that will start with the entire context and throw errors because those properties are not included in my `application-tag_test.yml` configuration.

Finally, any of the above locations I tried for the configuration is valid with the above annotations. The `application.properties` to specify a profile is not needed.

If anyone knows a way to specify **what** should be loaded into the context instead, I'd be very grateful for another solution.

Comment: Have you tried ´-Dspring.profiles.active=tag_test´ as a JRE parameter?

Comment: Just tried it, same result unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: "The difference here is that I've removed the \@ContextConfiguration annotation and I let Spring take care of all of that" - that worked the magic for me.  Instead of using \@ContextConfiguration to specify my test config class, I used the "classes" attribute on the \@SpringBootTest annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Boot Test documentations states that

```
External properties, logging, and other features of Spring Boot are installed in the context by default only if you use SpringApplication to create it.
```

This means that you need to have a working Spring Boot Application in order to test anything related to property loading in a test case.

Also, setting a list from properties needs a setter. This works:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "props")
public class TagIncluder {
    private List<String> tags;

    public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public List<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }
}

@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Autowired
    TagIncluder tagIncluder;
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("tag_test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TagIncluderTest {

    @Autowired
    private TagIncluder sut;

    @Test
    public void attachIncludedTags_shouldUseTagsInFileIfFileSpecified() {
        System.out.println(sut.getTags());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With some guidance of Jans suggestion above, I've managed to isolate the test to a slice. Auto configured testing is written about [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-tests), however that only touches on Springs predefined `@..Test` annotations.

If you dive deeper into the [`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html), for instance, you will find the `@ImportAutoConfiguration` annotation.

Using this, we can tell our test class to enable auto configuration for a single *slice* of our application. A tutorial is available [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/30/custom-test-slice-with-spring-boot-1-4). The full list of factories available for auto configuration can be found in the [spring-boot repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories).

Finally, this is the entire test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("tag_test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TagIncluder.class)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class)
public class TagIncluderTest extends ExchangeTestSupport {

    @Autowired
    private TagIncluder sut;

    @Test
    public void attachIncludedTags_shouldUseTagsInFileIfFileSpecified() {
        Exchange testExchange = createExchange();
        sut.attachIncludedTags(testExchange);

        Assertions.assertThat(testExchange.getIn().getHeader("tags", List.class))
            .size().isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(1);
    }
}
```

The class under test is untouched.

So now we can:

- Use profiles
- Use yaml
- Test only our desired class in Spring Context

This has been very enlightening :)

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this! 

@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class) really was the missing piece for me while trying to build up a partial ApplicationContext of our Service.